# How to use Microsoft Office 2016 behind a proxy?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I've just finished a fresh install of Microsoft Office 2016. When I run Microsoft Word, I obtain the start page with different propositions for creating a new document.

But the cursor is a spinning wheel and I can't use the interface. In the Activity Monitor I see `Microsoft Word (Not Responding)` with a CPU usage of about 27%.

What can I do?

P.S.: I'm using OS X 10.11.6 and Microsoft Word for Mac 15.26 (160910)

P.S.2: I'm working behind a proxy

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the fact I'm working behind a proxy.

After reading this article     [Microsoft Office 2016 and proxy URLs](http://www.amsys.co.uk/2016/07/microsoft-office-2016-proxy-urls/).

I've added the following url's:

```
nexus.officeapps.live.com
ocos-office365-s2s.msedge.net
config.edge.skype.com
officeclient.microsoft.com
odc.officeapps.live.com
store.office.com
omextemplates.content.office.net
nexusrules.officeapps.live.com
templateservice.office.com
```

to the bypass proxy list by going to : `System Preferences -> Advanced... -> Proxies` and filling the field `Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains`

P.S.: the domains must be separated by commas.

== EDIT ==

Today, I tried to refine this list given by the above mentioned article and I discover that Word was still running fine even without the list. Apparently, it's needed only on the first start of the application.

Comment: Just setup a proxy for the entire system then it should apply to every thing

Comment: I've already set a proxy for the entire system.

Comment: I see no reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your internet connection is on.
Check the size of the file, see if it matches from where you downloaded.
Restart and it probably works.

Source: Experience

Comment: My internet connection is working fine, but I'm behind a proxy. How do I tell this to Microsoft Office?